# Angular 9 to 10 upgrade - Typescript compilation warnings : *.ngtypecheck.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-upgrade

Post my upgrade from Angular 9 to Angular 10. ng build --prod throws the Typescript compilation unused warnings:

.ts is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

I have tried all solutions like removing the following include directive from tsconfig.app.json:

```
    "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
]
```

The only workaround that works is setting Ivy to False. But I do not wish to do that and instead want to find the real solution. I did not face it during my upgrade from Angular 8 to 9. Don't know why am bombarded with these warnings when upgrading to 10. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rolled back and re-upgraded Angular 9 to 10 using automatic migrations. This time my tsconfig got upgraded and I did not see any warnings.

I think fixing the extends would also work: "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json", if you do not wish to re-upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

A long story short I noticed the the problem arose for people with custom web kit settings.
So I
`ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular`
and the warnings disappeared.

To be honest, I aimed for updating `@ngtools/webpack` but copied the wrong text and by serendipity it solved my problem. (for now...)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the file 'tsconfig.app.json' to:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

only include the main file and if needed the polyfill. everything else will be indirectly loaded via references from the main file.

```
"include": [
        "./polyfills.ts",
        "./app-main.ts"
    ],
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing works. I get the same warnings. Only thing that works is setting Ivy to false in tsconfigapp.json  "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "enableIvy": false
    }